# Xamarin C# no deserializa json

Tags: c#, json, http, xamarin.forms

estoy tratando de convertir algunos parametros que recibo en un **json** en enteros, pero por alguna extraña razón no lo consigo, alguien quizá sepa en que estoy fallando???

```js
switch (response.StatusCod) {
  case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):
    res_Label_api.Text = "good";

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();



    // var xjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
    var xjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < DatosEnvio > (responseString); // hasta aquí  que recibe todos los datos del json
    var xjson_id = xjson.IdUsuario; // pero una vez aquí me dice que le paso un parametro null D:
    int xid = Convert.ToInt32(xjson_id);
}
```

```js
//modelo

public class DatosEnvio
{
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DatosEnvio DatosEnvio { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJson { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJsonDatos { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJsonTitulos { get; set; }
    public object tabla { get; set; }
    public object tablas { get; set; }
    public string bandera { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
}
```

```js
//json
{
    "DatosEnvio": {
        "Usuario": "prueba",
        "IdUsuario": "1",
        "Nombre": "Desarrollo Aige"
    },
    "DatosEnvioJson": null,
    "DatosEnvioJsonDatos": null,
    "DatosEnvioJsonTitulos": null,
    "tabla": null,
    "tablas": null,
    "bandera": "0",
    "mensaje": "Acceso exitoso"
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar el json?

Comment: Debes deserializar a tipo `RootObject` y luego hacer `var xjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject > (responseString);var xjson_id = xjson.DatosEnvio. IdUsuario;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas aplicando mal la deserialización ya que el tipo correcto es diferente al que aplicas. Debes deserializar a tipo `RootObject` y luego hacer

```
var xjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <RootObject>(responseString);
var xjson_id = xjson.DatosEnvio. IdUsuario;
```

Comment: Ni qué decir tiene que deberás controlar los posibles `null`  de `DatosEnvio`

Comment: ok , esto es muy extraño, "xjson.DatosEnvio. IdUsuario" ** IdUsuario ** = 1. Pero xjson_id  = null ,  D: